# RDD joinWithCassandraTable

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Can anyone please help me on the below query.
I have an RDD with 5 columns. I want to join with a table in Cassandra.
I knew that there is a way to do that by using "joinWithCassandraTable"

I see somewhere a syntax to use it.
Syntax:
RDD.joinWithCassandraTable(KEYSPACE, tablename, SomeColumns("cola","colb"))
 .on(SomeColumns("colc"))

Can anyone please send me the correct syntax??

I would like to actually know where to mention the column name of a table which is a key to join.

Comment: i dont want to load the entire table because its in huge in volume. So i dont want to register as

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JoinWithCassandraTable works by pulling only the partition keys which match your RDD entries from C* so it only works on partition keys.

The documentation is here
https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#using-joinwithcassandratable

and API Doc is here

http://datastax.github.io/spark-cassandra-connector/ApiDocs/1.6.0-M2/spark-cassandra-connector/#com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions

The jWCT table method can be used without the fluent api by specifying all the arguments in the method

```
def joinWithCassandraTable[R](
  keyspaceName: String, 
  tableName: String, 
  selectedColumns: ColumnSelector = AllColumns, 
  joinColumns: ColumnSelector = PartitionKeyColumns)
```

But the fluent api can also be used

```
joinWithCassandraTable[R](keyspace, tableName).select(AllColumns).on(PartitionKeyColumns)
```

These two calls are equivalent

Your example

```
RDD.joinWithCassandraTable(KEYSPACE, tablename, SomeColumns("cola","colb")) .on(SomeColumns("colc"))
```

Uses the Object from `RDD` to join against `colc` of `tablename` and only returns `cola` and `colb` as join results.

Answer (score 0):

Use below syntax for join in cassandra

```
joinedData = rdd.joinWithCassandraTable(keyspace,table).on(partitionKeyName).select(Column Names)
```

It will look something like this,

```
joinedData = rdd.joinWithCassandraTable(keyspace,table).on('emp_id').select('emp_name', 'emp_city')
```

Comment: how this answer is different from Russel's?